# Addition of Two Gridview Columns with conditions

Tags: asp.net, sql, t-sql

i have an asp.net project with coding C#.

Here i have a problem like this ; "i need to calculate the addition of the cells in my gridview" how can i do that.I need to sum IN and OUT minutes and divide them with 60 to find work hours.

select sum (cell1 + cell2) as something doesnt work because i have a grid like this;

```
NAME       WORK_TYPE        FM            FM_HOUR

-------------------------------------------------------

Mike         IN            -2800                

Mike         OUT            3400             ??

Jane         IN              400

Jane         OUT            -100             ??
```

What should be the ?? marks here.

I have written this but doesnt work OF COURSE. Because the program doesnt know how to take the values from there.

Here is the sample code;

```
SqlConnection conn;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        string strSQL = "UPDATE bilgiler3 SET FM_HOUR= SELECT SUM((FM WHERE WORK_TYPE='OUT') + (FM WHERE WORK_TYPE='IN')) / 60 "
        string bag_str = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["asgdb01ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        conn = new SqlConnection(bag_str);
        conn.Open();
```

.
.
.

Waiting your helps please.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The `GridView` allows for additions columns. I use the `TemplateField` and in the `ItemTemplate` I use labels and do math with the results of other cells data and show the results in them. Make a sub routine in the code behind and use a `For Loop` for each row. `row.FindControl` will help you find the labels and display the results. If your using `BoundFields` switch to `TemplateFields` so you can make controls you can find and get there values.

```
        <Columns>
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="some header info">
           <ItemTemplate >
            <asp:Label ID="lbId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Id") %>' />
           </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>...


For Each row As GridViewRow In gv.Rows
 Dim id As Label = TryCast(row.FindControl("lbId"), Label)
 'other variables
Next
```

Comment: I feel this would be the simplest way and less hits to your database and all the data is already loaded.

Comment: So, then, according to my table, where and what should i write ? 
i didnt understand the For Each row as GridViewRow ..... side.

Comment: That would go inside a sub routine that you can decide where to call it, like form_load, an update button click event, etc... It is where the math goes. You find and convert the values(since they are in string format) and display results in the labels inside the GV. http://forums.asp.net/t/1759693.aspx/1 has a great example of binding.